# JavaScript Linked List Confusion

Tags: javascript, linked-list, logic

I was doing some leet code and I have gotten really confused by how the linked list is being traversed and created.

Can someone please shed some light with regards to the question below

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} list1
 * @param {ListNode} list2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(list1, list2) {
    var list1_head = list1;
    
    let temp = new ListNode(0);
    let head = temp;
    console.log(head);
    
    if(list1 && list2){
        while(list1 && list2){
            if(list1.val < list2.val){ 
                temp.next = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
            }
            else{
                temp.next = list2;
                list2 = list2.next;
            }
            console.log('First Temp');
            temp = temp.next;
            console.log(temp);
        }
    
    }
    if(list1){
        temp.next = list1;
    }
    else if (list2){
        temp.next = list2;
    }
    console.log('--temp--');
    console.log(temp);
    console.log("Why isn't the value of temp 1 as set above");
    console.log('--head--');
    console.log(head);
    return head.next;
};
```

[image]

My question is why didn't temp = temp.next set the value of temp to be ultimately == to 1 as indicated in by the console log marked out by the red arrow but rather ended up becoming [1,2] as marked out by the blue arrow?

Shouldn't defining a value to a variable actually assign a value to the variable?
Such as

```
var apple = 'apple'
```

Will give the variable apple the value of 'apple'

But `temp = temp.next` just seems to to treat the variable temp like a pointer, pointing it to the next node of the linked list and does not actually alter that value of the linked list itself.

Comment: AFAIK javascript doesn't have a concept of pointers. Everything is a value, it's just that sometimes the value is a reference to an object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox In that case, why does setting temp = temp.next replace it's old values? The older values can still be accessed via the head variable

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean `list1_head`? If so, `list1_head = list1` assigns `list1_head` the value of `list1`. If you were to assign `list1` a different value, `list1_head` won't reflect that change.

Comment: "*In that case, why does setting temp = temp.next replace it's old values?*" because it does exactly what you told it to do *and* exactly the same as `var apple = 'apple'` - it changes the value of the variable. Period. It doesn't change anything else. Same as if you had `var a = "apple"; var b = a; a = "alpaca";` then `b` doesn't change. Again, the only change is what the value of `a` is. You're not also changing `b` by reference.

Comment: @VLAZ I have updated the question with more information to describe the issue better

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have updated the question with more information to describe the issue better

Comment: @VLAZ the value of variable head has changed to reflect new nodes added to the linked list variable temp although the value of head wasn't explicitly changed though

Comment: The thing that was in `temp` before you did `temp = temp.next` is not deleted.  There is another variable that contains a reference to the root of the structure (and all its children) - `head`.

Comment: @James why does it work differently than from var fruit = apple; fruit = grapes; which would completely change the value of the variable

Comment: What do you mean? The value of `fruit` changes, but neither `apple` nor `grapes` change.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} list1
 * @param {ListNode} list2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(list1, list2) {
    var list1_head = list1;
    
    let temp = new ListNode(0); //here it create the first node that is not presenti in list1 and list2 
    let head = temp; //head contains [0, null]
    console.log(head);
    
    if(list1 && list2){ //if both lists are defined
        while(list1 && list2){ //while they are both defined
            if(list1.val < list2.val){ // check if current value of list1 is < of list2
                temp.next = list1; //adds the lesser value as the next element on merged list
                list1 = list1.next; //list1 became list1 next (so in the next iteration list1.val changes to the next item
            }
            else{
                temp.next = list2; //same as above
                list2 = list2.next; //same as above
            }
            console.log('First Temp');
            temp = temp.next; //temp now is the new added node
            console.log(temp);
        }
    
    }
    if(list1){ //list2 is empty and there are some values in list1
        temp.next = list1; //add remaining items
    }
    else if (list2){ //list1 is empty and list2 doesn't
        temp.next = list2;//add remaining items from list2
    }
    console.log('--temp--');
    console.log(temp);
    console.log("Why isn't the value of temp 1 as set above");
    console.log('--head--');
    console.log(head);
    return head.next; //return head (initial node) minus the first fake node with zero
};
```

another possible solution of this task is the following

basically you define two function to turn your linked list into array and viceversa and you can use array function to merge and sort  and transform it back into linkedList

```js
function ListNode(val, next) {
    this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
    this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
}

const listToArray = list => list === null? []:[list.val, ...listToArray(list.next)]

const arrayToList = arr => arr.reduceRight((res, val) =>  new ListNode(val, res), null)
  
const mergeLists = (...lists) => arrayToList(lists.flatMap(listToArray).sort())

console.log(mergeLists( arrayToList([1, 3]), arrayToList([2, 4]), arrayToList([0, -1, 5])))
```